# Adding dot to rewrite rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to add a dot (`.`) to my variable in the last rewrite rule, and I have no idea where to put it in this syntax. Does it go after A-Z?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
ErrorDocument 403 /

Options ALL -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9/.]+)&([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Patch_No=$1&tab=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^patches php/patches.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([\s'0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: The dot may go anywhere within the square brackets, which are character sets.

Answer (score 0):

Since `RewriteRule ^([\s'0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)$` is a range of characters those rules apply.
In short you should be able to put it after the A-Z.
Just remember to escape the character.
Like so.

```
RewriteRule ^([\s'0-9a-zA-Z\._-]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```

However, you might want to consider changing the regex to a more inclusive in case there is a champion out there with special characters?
Maybe just say any character except a backslash question mark.

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/?]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```

Hope it helps!

ps: If champions will always start with a letter you could write it like this instead.

```
RewriteRule ^(\D[^\/?]+)$ index.php?Champion=$1 [NC,L]
```